# Lookup Class In LINQ, What is the underlying data structure?

Tags: .net, linq, algorithm, data-structures, .net-4.0

What is the underlying data structure of the Lookup Class In LINQ ? Is it a Hash Table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a hash table where each bucket contains a linked list and each item is part of a linked list of all item.

In other words, each item in the hash table contains a `key`, a list of `elements`, a link to the next item in hash bucket (`hashNext`), and a link to the next item in the hash table (`next`).