# Count same string count out of massive string list

Tags: c#, string, list, c#-4.0, linq-group

I have got over 600k lines of string. I want to group same strings and learn their counts.

So example

```
i go to school
i like music
i like games
i like music
i like music
i like games
i like music
```

So result will be

```
i go to school , 1
i like games  , 2
i like music , 4
```

How can I do that with the fastest possible way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) method is what you want. You'll need your strings to be in a list or something that implements `IEnumerable<string>`. The `File.ReadLines` suggested by spender will return an `IEnumerable<string>` that reads the file line by line.

```
var stringGroups = File.ReadLines("filename.txt").GroupBy(s => s);
foreach (var stringGroup in stringGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", stringGroup.Key, stringGroup.Count());
```

If you want them in order of least to most (as in your example) just add an `OrderBy`

```
...
foreach (var stringGroup in stringGroups.OrderBy(g => g.Count()))
    ...
```

Comment: Yes i can also read line by line but in that condition what would be the best approach ?

Comment: How are the lines stored? In a file? File.ReadLines is your friend. It returns an `IEnumerable<string>` that you can use for LINQ statements, but does not load the entire file into memory. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

Comment: @Ray from .net4 your method for reading line by line is redundant. See my previous comment.

Comment: @spender, sweet! I actually tried my code and it didn't work anyway. Will add your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq to implement it

```
IEnumerable<string> stringSource = File.ReadLines("C:\\file.txt");

var result = stringSource
    .GroupBy(str => str)
    .Select(group => new {Value = group.Key, Count = group.Count()})
    .OrderBy(item => item.Count)
    .ToList();

foreach(var item in result)
{
    // item.Value - string value
    // item.Count - count
}
```

Comment: Tried this but this is not ordered :) So how to order them by count ?

Answer (score 2):

Another, "oldschool" approach is iterating all lines and add them to a Dictioary(if not already present). The key is the line and the value is the count.

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, Int32>();
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\FileName.txt"))
     if (d.ContainsKey(line)) d[line]++; else d.Add(line, 1);
```

The advantage is, that works also on earlier framework versions.

Comment: Are you sure that ReadAllLines to "I have got over 600k lines of string" is a good idea?

Comment: @Viacheslav Smityukh: The question was not not IO related, actually the OP only said that he *has* 600k lines. My ReadAllLines is only an example on how to get them from file-system. I could easily remove that line from my answer.

Comment: Ray solution works awesome with extreme speed :) But thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Viacheslav Smityukh: Anyway, changed it to use [ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx#Y1365) what might be faster than [ReadAllLInes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx). But it is a 4.0 method and only faster when you start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned.

Comment: GroupBy uses `Lookup` which uses a HashTable anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775395/lookup-class-in-linq-what-is-the-underlying-data-structure

Comment: Bear in mind, that changing it to use ReadLines now makes it incompatible with versions of .Net before 4.0

Comment: @Chris: You are right and i've changed the code again to use `ReadAllLines` ;)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: Btw, this approach also takes only 200millis to group and count 700k lines into a Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
var groupedLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\samplelines.txt").GroupBy(x=>x);
groupedLines.ToList().ForEach(y => Console.WriteLine("Content: {0} - Occurences: {1}", y.Key, y.Count()));
```